# `\t` (tab) doesn't work properly when adding content to text file (Python)

Tags: python

I have a text file like this:

```
using System.Windows.Shapes;

namespace WpfApp1
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Interaction logic for MainWindow.xaml
    /// </summary>
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {       
        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }
    }
}
```

I want to load it in Python, add some more lines and save it. The problem is tha tif I create a variable like:

```
x = " \tNew Line with indend (4 spaces), \t \t(8spaces)    (4 spaces)."
```

Then the result of adding above and `x` looks like this:

[image]

Why `\t` is not equivalent to 4 spaces and `\t\t` to 8 spaces?

Comment: A tab character is a tab character. It is not equivalent to 4 spaces. You can configure your UI to display a tab as four spaces, but that still doesn't make a tab character equal to four spaces

Comment: So how can I work with Python and text? I added the screenshot of the result which is not aligned as I intented :( What should I change (in Spyder) to make `\t` working like 4 spaces?

Comment: A tab character means to go to the next tab stop. If tab stops are every 4 columns, this means it goes to the next multiple of 4 column. It doesn't just insert 4 spaces, because if you're currently at column 2 it only needs 2 characters.

Comment: Why not just use the number of spaces that you want?

Comment: Tab stops don't even need to be evenly spaced. The POSIX `tabs` command, for example, can set tab stops on arbitrary columns in the terminal, not just every `n`th column.

Comment: Or use an f-string with field widths in the formatting specifications? `f"{' ':4}"` will be 4 spaces.

Comment: Assuming your file is pasted correctly, there is no tab characters there, only spaces.  So adding tabs there is a bad idea anyway.  This is apart from explanations above.